# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource even if header is preset

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors, same-origin-policy

I running react app from http://localhost:3002 server and calling axios.post() action within to http://localhost:8080/api/file to upload a file.

I am using expressJS as backend. Also included cors module to enable CORS.

```
 app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3002'
}));
```

When request is made from client following errors is displayed in chrome's
console -

> ailed to load http://localhost:8080/api/file: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3002' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

But when I see in network, file is uploaded and returned 200 OK response.

Same thing works when I removed CORS headers from expressJS.

Why is is showing CORS error message if request is completed?
Why is it allowing cross origin request if not CORS headers are set?

Please help!!!

Comment: The browser makes the request but does not make it available to your app.  Check that the headers are indeed on the response. And also, Can we see where you define the routes?.

Comment: no actually you just need to allow the cors into your API codes. I think you use automation tool that enables your cors.